# Synchronization of BeginInvoke calls

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, synchronization, invoke

So I'm calling `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke()` to perform some UI actions in a `Timer.Elapsed` event. The timer is ticking fast, and multiple new instances of `BeginInvoke()` may stack up before a previous call is fully processed. After processing of current call is finished, I'm always interested in picking the latest instance of `BeginInvoke()` only, i.e. any previous unprocessed instances on the message queue should be discarded.

What is the correct way of emptying the Dispatcher's BeginInvoke queue to achieve this?

To demonstrate an example, consider that I'm reading value from a sensor in Timer.Elapsed event several times a second and then updating a complex UI to show the read values. This UI update action takes some time and during this time, one or more new instances of the read values stack up on the dispatcher queue to get rendered. Obviously, when I have got more recent values from the sensor, I'd want to discard all instances in the waiting line and just keep the current one, to be sent for rendering once the processor is free.

Comment: "_The_ correct way"? There is none. Your question is too broad, and has too many possible answers. What have you tried so far to accomplish this? ...

Comment: ... Did you, for example, try having a queue of delegates, where you only call `BeginInvoke()` when the queue is empty? Or maybe even just a single field (since you only care about the most recent), calling `BeginInvoke()` only when the field is `null`? Or maybe you might have tried, since you can't complete the operation within your timer interval anyway, using a longer interval? Or maybe not use a timer at all, and just call `BeginInvoke()` again at the end of each operation? Or maybe you should have a separate timer for UI updates, copying sensor readings at a slower interval for UI display

Comment: @PeterDuniho: I can't wait for the operation to complete before reading next value. The timer is kind of a *universal clock* that will tick at a constant rate.

Comment: @PeterDuniho: Also I do realize that this sounds a bit broad. But I'm specifically looking for a way to clear the Dispatcher queue.

Comment: _"I can't wait for the operation to complete..."_ -- you are missing the point of my comment. It's not an invitation for you to argue the point and nit-pick about what you can't do. It's about the fact that given what you posted, there are many different answers. That said, there are several suggestions in my comment that are still applicable even with that particular constraint. Instead of replying in comments, please edit your question to improve it. Provide a good [mcve] showing what you've tried, explain _all_ pertinent constraints, and what _specifically_ you need help with

Comment: _"I'm specifically looking for a way to clear the Dispatcher queue"_ -- you can't. It's not yours.

Comment: The Timer.AutoReset property is pretty deadly, having it initialized to *true* was not a great design decision.  You must set it explicitly to *false* yourself.  Call Start() in the invoked code to get the timer to tick again.  And do keep in mind that their is no benefit to using this Timer when all you do is get the code to run on the UI thread, use DispatcherTimer instead.

Answer (score 2):

There is no chance to dequeue callbacks since you are not managing the UI thread.
But you could use a [CancellationTokenSource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.cancellationtokensource(v=vs.110).aspx#Examples):

1. Pass the [CancellationTokenSource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.cancellationtokensource(v=vs.110).aspx#Examples) (CancellationTokenSource.Token)
   to the dispatcher and your callback.
2. Listen for cancellation by repeatedly invoking [CancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.cancellationtoken.throwifcancellationrequested(v=vs.110).aspx) inside your callback and catch the *OperationCanceledException* exception that will be thrown once the [CancellationTokenSource.Cancel()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321955(v=vs.110).aspx) was called
3. Use a catch block to catch *OperationCanceledException* and do the clean up in order to reverse state to prior of executing the callback
4. Before invoking the dispatcher with a new action you cancel all previous callbacks by invoking [CancellationTokenSource.Cancel()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321955(v=vs.110).aspx). This will trigger the ThrowIfCancellationRequested() to actually throw an *OperationCanceledException* inside the callback.
5. Invoke dispatcher with new callback and new *CancellationToken* from a fresh *CancellationTokenSource* instance and dispose all cancelled *CancellationTokenSource* instances.

This way you can cancel the dispatcher action e.g. in case it's long running or prevent it to be executed in case the action is still pending. Otherwise you have to enqueue the next dispatcher action and override the changes of the previous action.

*Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(...)* is equal to *Dispatchher.BeginInvoke(...)* but in addition it allows you to pass a cancellation token to the dispatcher.

Comment: Sounds like total overkill, when OP could simply write the current sensor reading into a field, and have a DispatcherTimer's Tick event handler read that field for display at a lower pace.

Comment: He said the action is time consuming. So it seems to be more efficient to cancel those long running tasks before continuing to spawn new actions on the dispatcher. Why spend time on something you now you going to discard for sure? Why wait? Given you have three actions in the queue and each takes 1 minute to execute. You would have to wait three minutes to get a valid value, because only the last one is valid.

Comment: Dispatcher offers infrastructure to cancel execution by using CancellationToken. This rather appeals clean to me.

Comment: Having a separate DispatcherTimer would mean not not call BeginInvoke *at all*.

Comment: You still would have several long running callbacks you maybe like to cancel. They are executed in high frequency so a lot of those long running actions will enqueue during runtime. You only changed the caller of the callback. From inside you are still using the Dispatcher since the timer executes on the Dispatcher. Code looks different thats all.

Comment: No you wouldn't. A single background thread (which the OP already has) writes a value into a field, with a high frequency. A single DispatcherTimer read the last written value from that field with lower frequency. That's all. No queues or tasks or whatever.

Comment: You need the possibility to cancel the previous job and discard its value otherwise each long running job has to complete. We don't know enough of the problem. It could also be wiser (e.g. in case of sensor readings) to calculate the moving average. This would also require polling.

Comment: No you don't. The "sensor thread" just overwrites the last value. The UI thread reads it. No need to cancel anything.

Comment: You should post your solution. I was just showing a simple way to abort dispatcher actions since dequeuing them is not possible.

Comment: The question is too broad for an answer. You are solving a problem that very likely does not exist.

Comment: You can't give a detailed solution since you don't know details, right. But you could also provide a workaround on how to dequeue dispatcher actions. He asked 
"What is the correct way of emptying the Dispatcher's BeginInvoke queue to achieve this?"
But I understand your solution. You're right. As I said, a typical scenario with sensor readings involved would calculate the moving average on new readings available instead of using the latest value only.